# Give X-Content-Type-Options headers for Error Pages?

Tags: php, security, http, response

I'm using a security scanning tool to check for vulnerabilities of my web application.

One of the results was a low warning about X-Content-Type-Options header being missing.

After some digging around, I found [this post on setting apache to emit nosniff headers](https://paulbradley.org/apache-http-security-headers/) and I put this code in to `httpd.conf` file;

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header unset ETag
  Header set X-Frame-Options: deny
  Header set X-XSS-Protection: "1; mode=block"
  Header set X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  Header set X-WebKit-CSP: "default-src 'self'"
  Header set X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: "master-only"
</IfModule>
```

And it worked! But then, my security scanning tool discovered that the 404 Not Found page on my web server was still giving me this warning. I'm guessing that the 404 error page is set to ignore the above rule somehow..

Can someone explain to me how to change this code or suggest an alternative so that error pages are included?

Could someone also maybe explain what the code above is doing? I don't actually know what `IfModule` or `mod_headers.c` actually means. Maybe that's why I'm having trouble in the first place.

Comment: `<IfModule mod_headers.c>` just means "Apply this code that modifies headers if the server module that makes it possible to modify the headers is available".

Comment: I believe the right thing to do is to throw away the "security scanning tool". Seriously.

Or does it say why it thinks the header field needs to be set???